# How to make non-smooth / stepwise scolling in a qgraphicsview

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I have a scene which has a basically table-like layout. Thus I'd like it to scroll like a table... one row or column at a time. Specifically, the upper left visible item should have it's upper left corner in the upper left corner of the viewport, unless the scrollbars are at their maximum (in which case it is the bottom/right item that is exactly in view). Pressing an arrow key should display the next row or column in that direction.

Normally that is easily achievable by inheriting QAbstractScrollArea and setting it up as appropriate, but QGraphicsView already does this. Is there someone who can think of a clever method for achieving this effect?

Answer (score 0):

just override `QGraphicsScene::keyPressEvent` and...

- right: move a cells width in positive x
- left: move a cells width in negative x
- up: move a cells height in negative y
- down: move a cells height in positive y

you'll have to disable this movement at the ends of the table, but it sounds a lot simpler that you might have initially thought

**EDIT**

overload `QGraphicsView::scrollContentsBy` to handle the scroll bar movement. You could store the dx and dy parameters and only scroll the movement when this value is greater than the size of a cell

Comment: That would take care of scrolling with the arrow keys, but not when using the scroll bars or other means of scrolling. I was hoping for something better.

Comment: I have been unable to look into your suggestion, though I think it will be hard to make it work intuitively correct with scrollbars and everything.

I might try to simply wrap the view in a new scrollarea, and handle the scrolling from that.